# Update tagger of annotated tag

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo that came over from svn. I converted the tag branches to actual git tags. I have set `$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, `$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` and `$GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` to `$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` and `$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` for all commits, using `git filter-branch`.

What I'm left with now, is that the **Tagger** of an annotated tag, is still different from the *Author* and the *Committer*. As seen in `git show`:

```
$ git show 1.0.0
tag 1.0.0
Tagger: Amedee Van Gasse <my@email>
Date:   Thu Jun 26 11:36:10 2003 +0000

1.0.0

commit 73ac747f5b6d26822c1f01654d63f05151cc6fad
Author: John Doe <john.doe@email>
Date:   Thu Jun 26 11:36:10 2003 +0000

foobar 1.0.0

Changelog: URL1
Release Notes: URL2
Download: URL3
```

So, my question is: how do I change `Amedee Van Gasse <my@email>` to `John Doe <john.doe@email>` *for the annotated tag object*? I am **not** asking about the commit object that the annotated tag points to, that is already covered. I am talking about the actual tag object.

The reason why I ask this: github.com will use the **Tagger** information for releases, not the Author or Committer.